# Is there something like [[noreturn]] in C# to indicate the compiler that the method will never return a value?

Tags: c#, noreturn

For some of my code I use a method which looks like this:

```
public static void Throw<TException>(string message) where TException : Exception
{
    throw (TException) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TException), message);
}
```

and I want to use it like this (simple example):

```
public int MyMethod()
{
    if(...)
    {
        return 42;
    }

    ThrowHelper.Throw<Exception>("Test");
    // I would have to put "return -1;" or anything like that here for the code to compile.
}
```

now, obviously, I know that there is no way `MyMethod` could never return anything, because it will always (indirectly) throw an exception.
But of course I get the compiler value "not all paths return a value".

That's why I am asking **if there is anything like the C++ `[[noreturn]]` attribute that I could use to indicate to the compiler that the code is actually valid**?

---

**EDIT:**
The reason for why I want to use a throwing helper class instead of throwing directly or using an exception builder, is [this statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exception-throwing):

> Members that throw exceptions are not getting inlined. Moving the
>   throw statement inside the builder might allow the member to be
>   inlined.

I actually measured the code and I would benefit (a little) from inlining, so I would be happy to find ways to achieve this.

Comment: `void` methods can, by definition, never return anything,

Comment: @BradleyUffner you're right, my example was too much simplified. I made an edit to make it a little more clear.

Comment: don’t make the helper throw anything, make it return an exception and then throw that form wherever you need to.

Comment: @InBetween I wanted to use another class for throwing, so that `MyMethod` [could possibly be inlined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exception-throwing), but using your suggested approach, `MyMethod` would definitely not get inlined, right?

Comment: Is inlining so important that you lower the readability of your code?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit very good objection, thank you. I guess I will overthink my design..

Comment: @BradleyUffner That's not relevant ... they do return, which is the issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way of doing this is to throw an exception with no branching. Something like this:

```
public int MyMethod()
{
    //Other code here.

    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

I actually thought of a way to do what you want:

```
public class Thrower
{
    public static TRet Throw<TException, TRet>(string message) where TException : Exception
    {
        throw (TException)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TException), message);
    }

    public int MyMethod()
    {
        if (new Random().Next() == 2)
        {
            return 42;
        }

        return Throw<Exception, int>("Test");
        // I would have to put "return -1;" or anything like that here for the code to compile.
    }
}
```

Comment: The "normal" way of doing it is to make the method `void`, not `int`.

Comment: @Adam you're right, thank you. I'd rather not use direct throwing for various reasons, but I will resort to that if there's no other way.

Comment: I think there isn't. After all, it isn't even smart enough to know that the method you're calling throws on all paths.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Making it `void` has no bearing on the problem, which is that the compiler complains that not all code paths return. And declaring a method that returns an `int` to be `void` makes no sense and isn't legal.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to get the compiler to understand that the method will always throw an exception and thus marks the end of code execution.

You are forced to

1. Call the method as the very last statement of your method (if your method is `void`)
2. Or add the necessary flow control statements after the method call to end the execution, *even though the code will never actually be executed*.

As you've pointed out, in a method with a return type, you will be forced to write the appropriate `return X;` statement where `X` is an appropriate value for the return type of your method.

There is no way around this.

Answer (score 3):

Bit late, but seems relevant:

Since Net Core 3.0 there is the `DoesNotReturn` attribute in `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis`

Reference: [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.doesnotreturnattribute?view=netcore-3.0)

Comment: It doesn't prevent the compiler from producing an error though, it will still give you a CS0161, "not all code paths return a value".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen because this is only with respect to nullability analysis if I understand this referenced article properly.